# How to control CSS arrow size

Tags: html, css

I created an arrow in CSS. Everything is working as it should except the size of the arrow. I am not sure how I can make it smaller.

How can I make the arrow smaller?

```css
#blue {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
}
#box2 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 right: 25%;
 z-index: 1;
}
#box2Text {
 color: #FFF;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 font-size: 2rem;
 font-weight: 300;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 padding: 80px;
 border: 6px solid #FFF;
 border-radius: 2px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
}
#arrow {
 margin-top: 10px;
 border: solid #FFF;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<section id="blue">
  <div id="box2">
    <span id="box2Text">View Services</span>
    <div id="arrow"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: When width and height are applied the arrows falls outside of the border (box).

Comment: can you show the desired output ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif See the illustration in my modified question. After adding the width and height the arrow is now positioning itself outside of the box. I am wanting it in the box where I put the x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the arrow as a pseudo element of the text div and you can easily place it and adjust its size:

```css
#blue {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
}

#box2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#box2Text {
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  padding: 80px;
  border: 6px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}
#box2Text:after {
  content:"";
  left:calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-top:40px;
  position:absolute;
  border: solid #FFF;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<section id="blue">
  <div id="box2">
    <span id="box2Text">View Services</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify CSS `width` and `height` attributes to `#arrow`. you might need to adjust the arrow position after that according to your needs

```css
#blue {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
}
#box2 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 right: 25%;
 z-index: 1;
}
#box2Text {
 color: #FFF;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 font-size: 2rem;
 font-weight: 300;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 padding: 80px;
 border: 6px solid #FFF;
 border-radius: 2px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
}
#arrow {
 margin-top: 10px;
 border: solid #FFF;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section id="blue">
  <div id="box2">
    <span id="box2Text">View Services</span>
    <div id="arrow"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: When I add this for some reason the arrow falls outside of the box.

Comment: @Paul it was always outside of the box but when you rotated it 45 degrees around its center while having 100% width half of it entered the box while the other half stayed out. that's why you need to further position the arrow where you want it to be

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
#blue {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
}
#box2 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 right: 25%;
 z-index: 1;
}
#box2Text {
 color: #FFF;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 font-size: 2rem;
 font-weight: 300;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 padding: 80px;
 border: 6px solid #FFF;
 border-radius: 2px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
}
#arrow {
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
 border: solid #FFF;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section id="blue">
  <div id="box2">
    <span id="box2Text"><div id="arrow"></div><span>View Services</span></span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: No. The arrow is in its correct form. Whenever I apply width and height to the arrow the position of it change.s

Comment: Of coure beacuse it isn't a real arrow icon , they are 2 sides border white of a little box  thant you rotated, so you need to adjust the margins when you increase the size